# running typescript with pm2, node and ts-node as argument

Tags: node.js, typescript, pm2, ts-node

This is the script to run typescript project:

```
node --require ts-node/register --loader=ts-node/esm --trace-warnings ./src/home-client.ts
```

With pm2, I tried:

```
pm2 start ./src/home-client.ts --node-args="--require ts-node/register --loader=ts-node/esm --trace-warnings"
```

Logs display an error: `0|home-cli | error: Script not found "ts-node/register"`

Whats the correct way to run typescript project with pm2 and node?

Answer (score 0):

Directly specifying node interpreter with --interpreter solved the issue.